# GNU sed: global substitution failing

Tags: sed

I have a file called test.csv with the following content:

```
T1,T2,T3,T4
10,2,3,17
10,2,5,14
10,2,2,16
15,1,17,15
12,1,9,25
```

I want to replace all the values 17 on the fourth column by 25. So I tried the command:

```
cat test.csv | sed -r 's/(([1-9]+,){3})17/\125/g'
T1,T2,T3,T4
10,2,3,17
10,2,5,14
10,2,2,16
15,1,17,15
12,1,9,25
```

As you can see, only the last row was modified, but not the second.

However, if I do: `cat test.csv |  sed -r "s/([0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+,)17/\125/"` I have the output I want. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your sed line didn't work is:

if you check your sed line carefully,

```
cat test.csv | sed -r 's/(([1-9]+,){3})17/\125/g' (your sed line)
```

you had `[1-9]` not `[0-9]`, fix that and try again, it should work for you.

also the `cat file` is not required. you can do `sed '...' file`

Comment: Yes, exactly! Thank you Kent, what a mistake... :)